# which one of these algorithm take more time?

Tags: algorithm, execution

I have these algorithm and I didn't find out which one takes more time.

> O((n^2)*log(n))

> O(n*(2^n))

I calculate the log of those but I can't understand which one takes more time.

> log((n^2)*log(n)) = 2log(n)+log(log(n))

> log(n*(2^n))=log(n)+n*log(2)

Comment: You got your answer from other users but I would like to comment on your use of log which you have to be careful with. log f(n)=\Theta(log g(n)) does NOT imply f(n)=\Theta(g(n)). For example even though log 2^n=\Theta(log 2^{2n}) but 2^n is NOT \Theta(2^{2n})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one, because:

```
2^n > n^2
```

and

```
n > log(n)
```

Comment: At least for `n>2`

Answer (score 1):

For a small range of values of `n` (roughly n = 5 (~4.738) to 26 (~25.783)) assuming natural logarithms, the first is larger than the second, but above that the second is always larger and becomes increasingly so as `n` increases.

Plotting it confirms this, here using *Mathematica*:

```
f1[n_] := Log[n^2]*Log[n]
f2[n_] := Log[n*(2^n)]

Plot[{f1[n], f2[n]}, {n, 1, 50}]
```

[image: Comparison of two Logarithmic Timings]

Comment: I think this answer would be much better if it included a second graph with much larger values of n, to show how much larger n*2**n becomes when n is big.

Comment: Also, the question was about `O( )`, so you can't compare for small values of n anyway because it's all up to a multiplicative constant

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate, reduce, or simplify those expressions.

..but hold on a moment and pay attention, that there is a *highest* order operand 2<sup>n</sup>, which grows *exponentially* - way faster (for sufficiently large *n*-s) than any other of the operands you have - namely n<sup>2</sup> or log<sub>2</sub>n.

Therefore, *O*((n*(2<sup>n</sup>)) would take way much more for sufficiently large inputs.

- input 1 → 2 operations
- input 2 → 8 operations
- input 3 → 24 operations
- input 4 → 64 operations
  ...
- input 10 → 10240 operations

I think you can see the pattern.

Note, that in terms of *asymptotic analysis*, we are always interested in large inputs, otherwise, for 1, 2 or very small inputs behaviour will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Not good enough at math to show proof, but simply filling in a value for "n" will give you a good indication. Let's take n = 100, base for log is 10.

```
# First algorithm
100^2 * log(100) = 10000 * 2 = 20000

# Second algorithm
100 * 2^100 = 100 * 1267650600228229401496703205376 = 126765060022822940149670320537600
```

I think it should be pretty obvious to always choose the first algorithm.

Comment: these log are based on 2.acually it doesn't really important.